# Odd Clipboard behaviour with FileDrop format

Tags: c#, file, clipboard

I'm facing a very strange Clipboard behaviour in my application. 
I have a Tcp server that receives some files, saves them to temp locations and puts them in the clipboard.
Here's a portion of the code:

```
filename = bReader.ReadString();
int dim = bReader.ReadInt32();
byte[] buffer = new byte[dim];
buffer = bReader.ReadBytes(dim);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(type, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();
}                    
String path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true, new String[]{path});
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

I can receive and save the file correctly, and also put he FileDrop data in the clipboard.
The problem is that i can paste the file only when my application gets closed. That's really weird...

After the application gets closed, i can paste with no problem and the pasted file is completely correct.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This *Could* happen, The clipboard is a shared system resource when you call `Clipboard.SetDataObject`, it calls the `user32` API function `OpenClipboard`, the problem here maybe because your program opens it so other application can't use it while your application is still running. this could also be a problem if you are using a custom meta files on it check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323530). Anyway I run this code "I am using 4.0 if that matters":

```
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true, new String[] { @"C:\test.txt" });
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

But I failed to review the issue you described, the windows can see the copy operation while the program is running and after Its closed. Are you only access to the `Clipboard` from that code? How are you reading the data back "pasting in your form"?

Comment: yeah, actually i managed to resolve the problem. The code above was executed in different threads, one per client. I thought the clipboard methods were completely thread-safe, as they state in the documentation, but apparently they are not. Anyway, i solved this problem by invoking the code above in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using data.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true, new String[] { @"C:\test.txt" }); will not set the clipboard DataObject properly. Tip! If you interrogate clipboard you have to reset it. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setfiledroplist?view=netframework-4.0

```
DataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
//Create and initializes a new StringCollection.
StringCollection strcolFileList = new StringCollection();
strcolFileList.AddRange(fileList);

try
{
dataObj.SetFileDropList(strcolFileList);
}
catch { }
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, Path.GetFullPath(strcolFileList[0]); ); //you can add this for fun
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
```